# Why and when do we add pointer in front of the lowerbound function in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdmap, lower-bound

So, I was solving a question and wrote this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int t;
   cin >> t;

   while (t--)
   {
      int n, x;
      cin >> n;
      map <int, vector<int> > m;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         cin >> x;
         m[x].push_back(i);
      }
      int prev_ind = n;
      int ans = 0;

      for (auto i : m)
      {
         if (i.second.back() < prev_ind)
         {
            ans++;
            prev_ind = i.second[0];
         }
         else
            prev_ind = *lower_bound(i.second.begin(), i.second.end(), prev_ind);
      }
      cout << ans << endl;
   }
}
```

So, when I remove the pointer from the front of `lower_bound` function, the code shows compilation error, can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: Adding `*` in front of `lower_bound` is not "adding pointer" to anything. It's *dereferencing* the iterator returned by the function. C++ is a context sensitive language and various symbols mean different things in different contexts. `*` doesn't always mean "pointer".

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a look at the [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
//^^^^^^^^ --> iterator
```

It **returns the iterator pointing to the first element** in the range *[first, last)* that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found.

Meaning, you will dereference the iterator (i.e. *"pointer from the front of `std::lower_bound`"* which is called *dereferencing* not *pointer*) to get the underline element and if you need the iterator for further operations, you will not dereference it.

In your case `i.second` has type `std::vector<int>` and doing

```
std::lower_bound(i.second.begin(),i.second.end(), prev_ind);
```

returns the `std::vector<int>::iterator` pointing to the element as per the condition. If you need to access the element, you need to dereference it.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator iter_prev_ind = std::lower_bound(i.second.begin(),i.second.end(), prev_ind);
prev_ind = *iter_prev_ind ;
```

which in short what you have written

```
prev_ind = *std::lower_bound(i.second.begin(),i.second.end(),prev_ind);
```

---

However, you should be careful before dereferencing the iterator return by the `std::lower_bound`, as it could also be the end iterator if no such element is found in the range *[first, last)* (credits *@eerorika*).

```
if(auto iter_prev_ind = std::lower_bound(i.second.begin(),i.second.end(),prev_ind);
   iter_prev_ind != i.second.end()) // if not iterator end
   prev_ind = *iter_prev_ind ;
```

---

Also, have a look into the followings

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Note that generally one should check whether the search found an element before indirecting through the pointer.